# Flutter: Create square icon in column in row in column without beeing out of bounds

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to put an interactive icon in a column and force it to be as wide as possible and square.
However, I don't even get to the column without everything being out of bounds.

Here is what I want: Grey are margins.

[image: Goal]

Here is what I got so far:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Input Text',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                        child: Placeholder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                        child: Placeholder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                height: 58,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Go')),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.link),
            label: 'Something',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot),
            label: 'Whatever',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Current Result**

[image: Current]

Now the problem is, as soon as I want to replace the placeholders with columns where I can add a square Icon with maximum width and a description underneath, I suddenly is out of bounds, even when I include Expanded multiple times.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming from `Placeholder` height, you can wrap it with `SizedBox` with providing height.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: Placeholder(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```